# react-native-navigation | Setting initial screen without putting it as tab?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to set initial screen on my react native app, but without putting it as a tab.

I mean I want to be able to reach the `navigator.push` outside a screen, something like this.

```
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
  tabs: [
    screen: 'Signup'
  ]
})

Navigator.push({
  screen: 'Landing',
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this doc https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/top-level-api

You need to use `Navigation.startSingleScreenApp`. Next, if u need open tab bar, just call `Navigation. startTabBasedApp` from anywhere in your application.

https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api

Also, you can try `resetTo(params)`

Comment: doc link 404: here you go: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/top-level-api

Comment: and the screen api one: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/screen-api