# How to display single screens before tab based screen in wix react native navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am trying display splash screen,location screen when the app open which are basically `singleScreenApp` and once location is selected i want to push the user to the `home screen` which is `TabBased screen` with side drawers.
For navigation i am using react native package called [wix react native navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/)

The problem i am facing is that when the page loads it directly take me to home page. The splash screen and login screen doesn.t come

Here is my code for each pages

**App.js** *(This is my entry point for the app)*

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import { registerScreens } from './screens/index';
registerScreens();
Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
    screen: {
        screen: 'app.splash',
        title: 'Splash',
    }
});
```

Then my splash screen code some images and and a timer to go to location screen.
On location screen i have a button when clicking on it it is setting `home.js` as root

**Code for my home screen *home.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {...} from 'react-native';
import "../resources/components/mainTabs";
class HomeScreen extends Component {
    render = () => {
        return (
            // BLOCK TO RENDER
        );
    }
}
module.exports = HomeScreen;
```

**mainTabs.js** *which contain the code for the tab based navigation*

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

Promise.all([
    Icon.getImageSource("md-home", 30),
    Icon.getImageSource("md-calendar", 30),
]).then(sources => {
    Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
        tabs: [
            {
                screen: "app.home",
                label: "Home",
                title: "Subscription",
                icon: sources[0],

            },
            {
                screen: "app.subscription",
                label: "Subscription",
                title: "Subscription",
                icon: sources[1],

            }
        ],
        drawer: {
            left: {
                screen: "app.sideDrawer"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

So this show the splash screen first then the tab screen but its taking directly to tab screen. Can anyone please help me Thank you
Thread i followed : [react-native-navigation | Setting initial screen without putting it as tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060091/react-native-navigation-setting-initial-screen-without-putting-it-as-tab)

Answer (score 0):

replace import "../resources/components/mainTabs"; with `import tabs from "../resources/components/mainTabs";`

then on click of login button just call `tabs()`
if the issue persists then show me your registerScreens() function so that i can provide furthur assistance